# LSA Model Improvement

Tags: topic-model, lda, gensim, similar-documents, lsi

I followed gensim's Core Tutorial and build an LSA Classification, topic modeling and Document Similarity model for newsgroups dataset.

My code is available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Zyik_bNi4_-o6qiBkORbDDSMW5krQosz?usp=sharing).

I need help with below 3 concepts.

1. **Topic Classification**: I get only 50% accuracy with KNN algo.
2. **Topic Modeling**: The words highlighted for each of the 20 topics doesnt stand out.
3. **Document Similarity**: I wrote a small test code to find that document similarity also doesnt produce great results.

I am going to follow up it with other best models like LDA. However I am eager to know if I can improve my current LSA model. Any help here, would be really appreciable. Thanks!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Code Review is off topic for this site.

Comment: Fine. If my post falls under Code Review, it can be closed. However the code and dataset is publicly available (from gensim and sklearn), I just pulled their code and thought of having a conversation around LSA instead of asking questions in many different posts.